# SELinux is not logging anywhere

Tags: centos, logs, selinux

I have SELinux in permissive mode enabled on CentOS7 system. But it doesn't seem to produce any logs. No new files in `/var/log/audit`, `grep -i selinux /var/log/messages*` finds nothing.

sestatus returns:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the audit packages installed? If so, is `auditd` enabled and running?

When you don't have the audit packages installed, `audit` & `audit-libs` and have the `auditd` service running, the logs will stop showing up in where you expect (`/var/log/audit`). When this is the case, they will show up in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: I have auditd running, but no new logs in /var/log/audit. I tried restarting the service with systemctl, but  got this: Operation refused, unit auditd.service may be requested by dependency only.

Comment: That is correct. Audit, unfortunately, does not play well enough with systemd. Use the classic service command for auditd and it will restart gracefully.

Comment: Allright, restarting it this way helped, thanks!

Comment: "Where do the AVC (Access Vector Cache) denials go to?" [Doc for Red Hat 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting), [Doc for Red Hat 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-What_Happens_when_Access_is_Denied)